# Create a database table using heroku on Postgresql in windows?

Tags: python, windows, flask, heroku, create-table

```py
    import from os
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

    engine= {Database url #which is a heroku url }
    db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    db.commit()

    #Check for environment variable
    if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")
```

I made the sql to create the table but I am having difficulty creating a table in the database and inserting the initial values using this below

```
    CREATE TABLE Users (
        isbn INTEGER,
        title VARCHAR(30),
        author VARCHAR(30)
    );
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: I was not able to connect to my database to create tables and insert values. The problem was with the Postgress installation which kept failing. However i used the SQL SHELL to connect to heroku database without using the python file above. Thanks though.